# How did typhoon 轩岚诺 get its name?

Tags: names

I was intending to go hiking, but I can't thanks to [typhoon 轩岚诺](http://cd.nbd.com.cn/articles/2022-09-04/2451170.html).  Now I'm curious as to how this typhoon came to be called 轩岚诺, which looks like it could be an actual person's full name.

**Question**: How did typhoon 轩岚诺 get its name?

There's a explanation of how typhoons get their names at [Zhihu](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/36097072) but it doesn't seem to cover this particular name (talking about mythology, historical figures, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

> 命名由来

> 由于2016年第26号超强台风“洛坦”重创菲律宾，因此台风委员会于2017年2月在日本横滨举行的第49次届会议中决定将“洛坦”除名  ，并由老挝于2018年提供新名称“轩岚诺”（Hinnamnor）以取代之，意思为老挝的一个国家保护区的名称，即老挝境内的轩岚诺国家保护区

> As the 26th super typhoon "Lotan" in 2016 hit the Philippines hard, the Typhoon Committee decided to delist "Lotan" at its 49th session held in Yokohama, Japan in February 2017.  In 2018, a new name "Hinnamnor" was provided to replace it, meaning the name of a national reserve in Laos, namely the Hinnamnor National Reserve in Laos

轩岚诺 is a transliteration of 'Hinnamnor' which is named after 轩岚诺国家保护区 (Hinnamnor National Reserve) in Laos

[reference](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8F%B0%E9%A3%8E%E8%BD%A9%E5%B2%9A%E8%AF%BA/59800100)

Answer (score 1):

台风轩岚诺（英语：Typhoon Hinnamnor，国际编号：2211，联合台风警报中心：WP122022，菲律宾大气地球物理和天文管理局：Henry）是2022年太平洋台风季第11个被命名的风暴。“轩岚诺”一名由寮国提供，取自寮国中部的轩岚诺国家公园（英语：Hin Namno National Park）[1][2]。此名字第一次使用，取代在2016年重创菲律宾的台风纳坦。

Also name Typhoon Xuan Lan Nuo.

https://www.wikiwand.com/zh-hans/%E9%A2%B1%E9%A2%A8%E8%BB%92%E5%B5%90%E8%AB%BE_(2022%E5%B9%B4)